# Using xcode 6.4, Hide/Unhide rows in TableView sections when there are many sections

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a Table with many sections and each section also has rows. How can I hide/unhide the rows per section? the table will be easier to manage if the user only sees sections and can 'tap' the section to see the row selections.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `tableView(_, numberOfRowsInSection)` in the table view's data source to return either 0 (to hide them) or the actual value. Then, in the table view's delegate, implement `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` to return a view that listens for taps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers. Is it possible to point me to a simple 'working' code showing how this works. I'm a beginner at Xcode/swift.